# How to make a responsive table header?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have this table, but elements at last column don't fit the entire table when display is in a big size. What am I doing wrong?

## Large

[image]

## Medium

[image]

## Small

[image]

## I have

```
<div class="panel-body">
  <table class="table mb30" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th width="5%">#</th>
        <th width="30%">Site Name</th>
        <th width="40%">Site URL</th>
        <th width="25%">Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>URL</td>
        <td>Action</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

---

I've put together a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bheng/pkjbpsr7/)

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: What is it you want to change when the screen size changes? The % widths?

Comment: Seems like its already responsive to me.

Comment: @DustinPoissant : As you can see, in a large screen, I want  it stay on the right of the page.

Comment: I want my action buttons to stay on the right, just just it has a class pull-right.

Comment: Well maybe that's the kind of information you should put in the question not just an image with an orange box

Comment: Don't give the action column a percentage. https://jsfiddle.net/pkjbpsr7/1/

Comment: I've tried that, I got [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/56134944/Screen%20Shot%202016-02-04%20at%202.32.31%20PM.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't give the action column a percentage width. If you give table headers a percentage that adds up to the total and leave out a column, all the % based columns will take up as much room as they have available.

https://jsfiddle.net/pkjbpsr7/1/

For example:

```
  <tr>
    <th width="5%">#</th> <!-- This column and the next two will fill the space available. -->
    <th width="30%">Site Name</th>
    <th width="65%">Site URL</th>
    <th>Action</th> <!-- This one will just chill off to the side and only take up as much room as it has width -->
  </tr>
```

If you need it to take up a certain amount of space, you can always give it a min-width:

https://jsfiddle.net/pkjbpsr7/4/

```
    <th width="5%">#</th>
    <th width="30%">Site Name</th>
    <th width="65%">Site URL</th>
    <th id="min-width">Action</th> <!-- This will take up 100px per it's min-width -->
```

Comment: I've tried that my button stack on top of each others. When I do that :(

Comment: Give it a min-width.

Comment: See it [HERE](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/56134944/Screen%20Shot%202016-02-04%20at%202.32.31%20PM.png)

Answer (score 2):

You need `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">` in the header.

then use:

```css
@media screen and (max-width : 725px ){
 #id {}
 .class {}
}
```

change max-width to what you want.